# Should MongoDbContext Static?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-core

I've a ASP.NET Core ntier ecommerce application with Mongo Db. I am new on MongoDb by the way. And this application will works on heavy load.

I've created a db context to connect Mongo Db but i am confused that should i use a static class for the context?

Mongo document says this :

> The client instance now holds a pool of connections to the server or
> servers specified in the connection string.

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.15/getting_started/quick_tour/

and this :

> Store your MongoClient instance in a place that is globally accessible
> by your application.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/connection-pool-overview/

My context class is here, i think i should call it with Singleton with DI. What should i do? Thanks

```
public class MongoDbContext
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

    public MongoDbContext(IOptions<MongoSettings> settings)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
        _database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.Database);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<TEntity> GetCollection<TEntity>()
    {
        return _database.GetCollection<TEntity>(typeof(TEntity).Name.Trim());
    }
    public IMongoDatabase GetDatabase()
    {
        
        return _database;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should keep only one instance of `MongoClient` per cluster per application

> Use one MongoClient instance per application unless the application is
> connecting to many separate clusters.
>
> MongoClient objects are thread-safe in most drivers.

[Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/connection-pool-overview/#use-an-instance-of-your-driver-s-mongoclient-object)

You can keep that as Singleton.

Comment: Yes, this is current recommendation, but with some notes about particular use cases, it will work in the same way without singleton as well, but better use it as singleton